# php access array data misunderstanding

Tags: php, arrays

Given the following array `$testarray`:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["brand"]=>
    string(4) "fiat"
    ["year"]=>
    string(4) "2001"
    ["color"]=>
    string(4) "blue"
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access the data inside with:

```
foreach($testarray[0] as $key => $value)
{
    $newresultado = $value['brand'].$value['year'].$value['color'];
}
echo $newresultado;
```

I do not get an error returned, but I do get an empty string.

I checked a lot of topics and this should be correct. Why am I getting the empty string?

Comment: Maybe declare the string `newresultado` first.

Comment: Try removing the `[0]` from the foreach, you are iterating over the elements then looking for a brand.

Comment: Did you give up?

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through the values under the `0` index so the indexes you are referencing don't exist.  Also, if you have more than one then each will overwrite the other so you would use `.=` instead:

```
$newresultado = '';

foreach($testarray as $key => $value)
{
    $newresultado .= $value['brand'].$value['year'].$value['color'];
}
echo $newresultado;
```

If there will only ever be one item then there is no need to loop:

```
echo $testarray[0]['brand'].$testarray[0]['year'].$testarray[0]['color'];
```

You need to develop with these settings which would have shown you notices and errors:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `[0]` from `$testarray`.